# Insert/update script not updating at all

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that runs and inserts as it should but it's not updating, at least not on the initial batch. If I run the script, the first and main SELECT query gets about 800 records. It inserts and performs the logic I have below (multiple if, elseif and for loops at bottom of script) but I need it to process for each individual record from the initial select.

So: Select all records, for first record perform select on destination table to see if the sku exists for this dealer. IF not, insert, if it does then update.

The problem is, when I run this for the initial data porting, the destination table is empty so it's not checking against anything. I added a foreach in my code to say "For every single record, perform the select/check on destination table, then perform logic to determine if insert or update"

I included a fiddle below as well but using these values to select from:

```
(12345, 133, 1234, '2018-02-02', 10, 10),
(12345, 133, 1235, '2018-02-02', 10, 10),
(12345, 133, 1236, '2018-02-02', 10, 10),
(12346, 133, 1234, '2018-03-02', 30, 10);
```

The logic is that for every dealer, they should records for each sku equal to their store number at most.

With the data above, It should insert 10 records for the first sku, 10 for the 2nd sku, 10 for the 3rd sku and then since the 4th sku is the same as the 1st and the date is before the expire_date, we would update that row 30 times, based on the quantity being more than the storefronts.

The logic is weird, I know. But that part works, I just need help with the foreach logic to make sure I'm performing the check for each record from the initial select so that it can actually determine if it needs to update.

I can clarify as needed.

```
$detailStatCheck = "
    SELECT 
         orderNum,
         custNum,
         sku,
         shipDate,
         quantity,
         stores
    FROM orders
    WHERE custNum= 133";

try {
    $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
    $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute();
    $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch();
    print_r($count2);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

$existingCheck = "
    SELECT 
        sku,
        custNum,
        expire_date,
        quantity
    FROM individualProducts
    WHERE customer = :customer
        AND sku = :sku
";

$updatePlacement = "
    UPDATE individualProducts
    SET expire_date = DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(current_date(), CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY),
       quantity = :quantity
";

$insertPlacement = "
    INSERT ignore INTO individualProducts (sku, customer, start_date, expire_date, locations, quantity)
    VALUES(
        :sku,
        :customer, 
        date_add(convert(:SHIPDATE,date), interval 7 day) as start_date,
        date_add(convert(:SHIPDATE,date), interval 127 day) as expire_date, 
        :stores,
        :quantity)
";

$checkExisting = $MysqlConn->prepare($existingCheck);
$insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
$update = $MysqlConn->prepare($updatePlacement);

$orders = [];
while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $orders[] = $row2;
     foreach($orders as $order){

     $values = [
        ":customer" => $row2["customer"],
        ":shipDate" => $row2["shipDate"],
        ":stores" => $row2["stores"],
        ":quantity" => $row2["quantity"],
        ":sku" => $row2["sku"],
     ];

     $existingRslt = $checkExisting->execute($values);
     $count3 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     //if no existing records, insert. If quantity is greater than stores, insert records to equal store number. If quantity is less than stores, insert records to equal quantity

     if(empty($count3)){
        print_r("Inserting");
        if($row2["quantity"] > $row2["stores"]){
            for($i=0; $i<$row2["stores"]; $i++){     
                    try{
                        $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                    }catch(PDOException $ex){
                     echo "QUERY THREE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                    }
            }
        }elseif($row2["quantity"] < $row2["stores"]){
            for($i=0; $i<$row2["quantity"]; $i++){   
                    try{
                       $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                    }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    echo "QUERY THREE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                    }
             }
         }
      }elseif(!empty($count3) && curdate() < $count3['expire_date']){
                print_r("Updating");
                if($row2["QUANTITY"] > $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2['STORES']; $i++){
                        try{
                            $updateRslt = $update->execute($values3);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY FIVE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }elseif($row2["QUANTITY"] < $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2['QUANTITY']; $i++){
                        try{
                            $updateRslt = $update->execute($values3);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY FIVE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
            print_r("Inserting");
            if($row2["quantity"] > $row2["stores"]){
              for($i=0; $i<$row2["stores"]; $i++){   
                    try{
                        $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                    }catch(PDOException $ex){
                     echo "QUERY THREE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                    }
               }
            }elseif($row2["quantity"] < $row2["stores"]){
              for($i=0; $i<$row2["quantity"]; $i++){     
                    try{
                       $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                    }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    echo "QUERY THREE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                    }
             }
         }
      }

$MysqlConn = null;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0efffb

EDIT:

Create table syntax

```
create table orders(
 orderNum int(11),
 custNum int(11),
 sku int(11),
 shipDate DATE,
 quantity int(11),
 stores int(11) 
);

insert into orders
values (12345, 133, 1234, '2018-02-02', 10, 10),
   (12345, 134, 1234, '2018-02-02', 10, 10),
   (12345, 135, 1234, '2018-02-02', 10, 10),
   (12346, 133, 1234, '2018-03-02', 30, 10);

create table individualProducts(
 sku int(11),
 customer int(11),
 start_date DATE,
 expire_date DATE,
 locations int(11),
 quantity int(11)
 );
```

Comment: I did provide the fiddle with the create tables, but I've added them in the above question as well

Comment: Shoot, sorry that was the wrong code. I updated it now, it should just be to update individualProducts. I'm only using 2 tables

Comment: The thing it is most weird here is that your update statement does not have a WHERE statement which would cause ALL registries in that table to be updated if the update is ever called which isn't called anywhere in the code.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think that is part of the issue. I actually got the update to trigger by moving my foreach, however, like you said it is updating every record. So I need to update that with a 'where' clause which is what I thought the loop was doing the logic for

Comment: @JorgeCampos is there a more specific way to say ```update these things for this exact record``` based on my array?

Comment: Well in the if block that should do the update (got it from the `print_r("Updating");`) there is no call to the update statement whatsoever. you are actually inserting on that block

Comment: For your last question, based on your data you should add all fields in your where statement since there is nothing that can be identified as unique.

Comment: Why do you have two connections (`$DB2conn` and `$MysqlConn`) ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I changed that to call the update, I saw where the error was now. So it is calling now, but I'll have to add in the fields

Comment: @dakis because the select is coming from a db2 connection, and I'm inserting into a mysql connection

Comment: Thanks @dakis I got that changed and trying it now. Seems like it's updating properly now, but I'm trying to see if it's looping too many times. It's taking longer than expected

Comment: In `$values` array, correct is: `":customer" => $row2["custNum"],`

Comment: In `$insertPlacement`, correct is: 2x `convert(:shipDate,date)`.

Comment: Do you see the problem with my for each?

Comment: Sure, in this case dealer basically means customer. So they might buy three different products which means 3 different skus, at any amount of quantity

Comment: In the _orders_ table, a record represents a product (described by its _sku_) that a customer (described by _custNum_) has bought in the amount described by _quantity_. Right? And the product should be delivered to the customer on the date described by _shipDate_. Right?

Comment: Right. So the logic is to say that if they have 10 stores and bought 25 of one sku, then it would insert 10 records, then overwrite/update 15 times. Then if it runs for 5 more of that same sku, it sees that 10 records exist for that sku where today is before the expire_date so it would then only update 5 of those records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167384/discussion-between-dakis-and-tom-n).

Comment: This seems fantastically OTT for what appears to be a simple INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY problem

Comment: I usually use insert on duplicate key, or even replace. But because of the need to keep multiple copies of certain records, that doesn't work here. Thus the logic I'm using to determine whether to insert or update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you know that, but, if you are more interested in regard of error handling, you could read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) (general) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) (for PDO) article.

It was still hard to understand the *update* phase. I just hope, you can at least take some ideas from my code. Don't accept my answer. I posted it only in order to help you a bit. Ask me anything if you want.

#### index.php

```
<?php

require 'connections.php';

/*
 * ====================
 * Get the orders list.
 * ====================
 */
$sql = 'SELECT 
            orderNum,
            custNum,
            sku,
            shipDate,
            quantity,
            stores
        FROM orders
        WHERE custNum = :custNum';

$ordersStatement = $DB2conn->prepare($sql);
$ordersStatement->execute([
    ':custNum' => 133,
]);
$orders = $ordersStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
 * ======================================================
 * Prepare the sql for selecting the individual products.
 * ======================================================
 */
$sql = 'SELECT 
            id,
            expire_date,
            quantity
        FROM individualProducts 
        WHERE 
            sku = :sku 
            AND customer = :customer
        ORDER BY id DESC';

$productsStatement = $MysqlConn->prepare($sql);

/*
 * ====================================================
 * Prepare the sql for inserting an individual product.
 * ====================================================
 */
$sql = 'INSERT INTO individualProducts (
            sku,
            customer,
            start_date,
            expire_date,
            locations,
            quantity
        ) VALUES (
            :sku,
            :customer, 
            DATE_ADD(CONVERT(:shipDate, date), INTERVAL 7 DAY),
            DATE_ADD(CONVERT(:shipDate, date), INTERVAL 127 DAY),
            :locations,
            :quantity
        )';

$insertProductStatement = $MysqlConn->prepare($sql);

/*
 * ===================================================
 * Prepare the sql for updating an individual product.
 * ===================================================
 */
$sql = 'UPDATE individualProducts
        SET 
            expire_date = DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(current_date(), CHAR(20)), "%Y-%m-%d"),INTERVAL 129 DAY),
            quantity = :quantity
        WHERE id = :id';

$updateProductStatement = $MysqlConn->prepare($sql);

/*
 * ==================================
 * Update/insert individual products.
 * ==================================
 */
foreach ($orders as $orderItem) {
    $orderItemCustomer = $orderItem['custNum'];
    $orderItemSku = $orderItem['sku'];
    $orderItemShipDate = $orderItem['shipDate'];
    $orderItemQuantity = $orderItem['quantity'];
    $orderItemStores = $orderItem['stores'];

    /*
     * =================================
     * Get products by sku and customer.
     * =================================
     */
    $productsStatement->execute([
        ':sku' => $orderItemSku,
        ':customer' => $orderItemCustomer,
    ]);
    $products = $productsStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!$products) { // No individual products found.
        // How many products should be inserted?
        $numberOfProductsToInsert = ($orderItemQuantity >= $orderItemStores) ? $orderItemStores : $orderItemQuantity;

        // Insert the product $numberOfProductsToInsert times.
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfProductsToInsert; $i++) {
            $insertProductStatement->execute([
                ':sku' => $orderItemSku,
                ':customer' => $orderItemCustomer,
                ':shipDate' => $orderItemShipDate,
                ':locations' => $orderItemStores,
                ':quantity' => $orderItemQuantity,
            ]);
        }
    } else { // Individual products found.
        $numberOfProducts = count($products);
        $numberOfUpdatedProducts = 0;
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', time());

        // How many products should be updated?
        $numberOfProductsToUpdate = ($orderItemQuantity >= $orderItemStores) ? $orderItemStores : $orderItemQuantity;
        $numberOfProductsToUpdate = ($numberOfProductsToUpdate >= $numberOfProducts) ? $numberOfProducts : $numberOfProductsToUpdate;

        // Update each product (maximal $numberOfProducts).
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($numberOfUpdatedProducts == $numberOfProductsToUpdate) {
                break;
            }

            $productId = $product['id'];
            $productExpireDate = $product['expire_date'];

            if ($currentDate < $productExpireDate) {
                $updateProductStatement->execute([
                    ':quantity' => $orderItemQuantity,
                    ':id' => $productId,
                ]);

                $numberOfUpdatedProducts++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### connections.php

```
<?php

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER! */

/*
 * Create a DB2 connection.
 */
$DB2conn = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);

/*
 * Create a MySQL connection.
 */
$MysqlConn = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);
```

#### Create table syntaxes

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderNum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custNum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stores` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `individualProducts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expire_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `locations` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```